# Save all recorded bag files with `rosbag record`

Tags: ros, linux, ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am recording data from a [range scanner](https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_scan_xd/tree/master) with ROS Melodic using the following command:

> rosbag record -o nav310_ws/bagFiles/session --split --duration=1 --max-splits 1 /cloud

In the `bagFiles` folder, only the latest bag files are kept. So I was wondering how to copy all recorded bag files and save them to another folder. I tried the following command just after the first one, but it did do anything.

> cp -a nav310_ws/bagFiles/.
> nav310_ws/allBags/

Thank you for any suggestion you could provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417241/save-all-recorded-bag-files-with-%60rosbag-record%60/) by [Ben Brian](https://answers.ros.org/users/98380/ben-brian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to keep the older bag files, you should not be using the `--max-splits 1` option. The command:

```
rosbag record --help
```

explains what the options do.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2